# "List does not contain definition for Fill"

Tags: c#, list, collections

I have a Class:

```
public class ItemsList
{
    private List<Item> items;

    public List<Item> Items
    {
        get { return items; }
        set { items = value; }
    }

    public void Fill()
    {
        items = ItemDB.GetItems();
    }
```

and Form1 code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Items.Fill();
        FillItemsBox();
    }
```

My error is

```
...List < Item  >Does not contain definition for 'Fill' and no extension method 'Fill' accepting a first argument of type ... List < Item >.
```

I have almost identical code where I do not have this problem, only the variable names are different. It seems strange that my Form1 doesn't acknowledge that there is a method 'Fill', which doesn't appear to be my problem. Is the problem elsewhere possibly?

Comment: "Almost identical code" doesn't count. Look at the *actual* types between the working and failing cases.

Comment: @RagingBull Please don't add "any help would be appreciated...", etc. That is unnecessary fluff that is generally excluded from Stack Overflow.  Of course any help would be appreciated - it's a given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling Items.Fill() where Items is of type List. The Fill method is in the ItemsList class. So the call must be in that class:

```
ItemsList myItemsList;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myItemsList.Fill();
    FillItemsBox();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Form1.Items` property is of type `List<Item>`, but it appears what you meant to do was make:

```
partial class Form1
{
  ItemList Items { get; set; }

  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Items.Fill();
    FillItemsBox();
  }
}
```

Comment: Once I get my brain wrapped around classes I'll be able to do all those cool { get; set; } things and be able to follow them.